# is there a better way to add a list of integers containing users id as serialized json string to SQL as one record?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a Blazor app that's similar to Facebook groups, I have to make a notification function where users can receive a notification message when someone comments on a post they're following, I already created an SQL table for tracked posts that contains user id together with post id as composite key, but now I got lost with how to handle notifications, I was thinking to add Notification table that contains three columns, id, message, and receivers list(varchar as serialized JSON string and deserialize it when asking for data), is there any better way to do so?

Comment: Why not add one entry (row) for each recepient?

Comment: You should normalize that into separate rows, do not store multiple pieces of information in a single column. So a table `Notification (PostID, ReceiverId)` and the message is part of the `Post` not `Notification`